# Shift a column by one in R

Tags: r

```
data <- data.frame(id = factor(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)),name = factor(c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j")),date = factor(c(NA,"July",NA,"August",NA,"September",NA,"October",NA,"November")))
```

I want to shift 3rd column up by one. so that it looks like

head(data)

```
id name   date
1   a     July
2   b     NA
3   c     August
4   d     NA
5   e     September
```

Can you please help me? Also, I would like to know if the process will be

different for simple integer.

Comment: `data$date <- dplyr::lead(data$date)`

Comment: How do you replace the last element in the 3rd column.

Comment: Does the column wrap?  What I mean by this is, does the current first element rollover to become the last element of the `date` column after the operation?

Comment: Try `library(data.table);setDT(data)[, date := shift(date, type = 'lead')]`

Comment: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.10.4/topics/shift

Answer (score 0):

Using the tidyverse collection, you can achieve this in a simple line of code as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- data.frame(id = factor(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)), 
        name = factor(c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j")),
        date = factor(c(NA,"July",NA,"August",NA,"September",NA,
                     "October",NA,"November")))

data$date %>% lead()

   id name      date
1   1    a      July
2   2    b      <NA>
3   3    c    August
4   4    d      <NA>
5   5    e September
```

If the variable type is an integer, you can use the same process.  For example, if you were to change "id" to an integer, you can use the same function:

```
data$id %<>% as.character %>% as.numeric

data$id %>% lead()

    id name      date
 1   2    a      July
 2   3    b      <NA>
 3   4    c    August
 4   5    d      <NA>
 5   6    e September
```